# Minkowski infinity sum

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let
$$
\ell^p = \left\{(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}: a_n\in\mathbb{R} \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and }\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^p<\infty \right\}.
$$
How can we prove the following inequality:
$$
\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n+b_n|^p \right)^\frac{1}{p}\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^p \right)^\frac{1}{p}+\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^p \right)^\frac{1}{p}.
$$

My inicial attempt was to use Minkowski inequality but i couldn't prove it for infinty.

Comment: Use Minkowski for finite sums up to $N$, and then let $N$ tend to $+\infty$.